# null response body from entity annotated with @Data with lombok springboot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller, lombok

I have an entity annotated with @Data of lombok and I also have a simple controller. It returns an empty JSON data when I use @Data and it returns list of data when I remove @Data by explicitely using setters and getters without lombok.

How can I also call setters and getters when I use @Data expcilitely?
I am just using constructor to avoid this issue but sooner or later, I need to change values as most fields are mutable.

Is there a real solution for this problem?
I have checked some but still don't see solutions.

Comment: Your question is perfectly unclear. What versions do you use? How does you class look like? Simply use delombok and replace `@Data` by what it produces. Does it work? Compare it to the working code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the outlined problem. A [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43814410) is available on Github to show that Lombok-annotated model objects get serialized just fine. Can you add your code where you are facing problems?